# How to pass hidden date value from one JSTL to another?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I get http 400 issue(bad syntax) after

```
<input type="hidden" id="_orderDate_id" name="orderDate" value="${orderDate}"/>
```

But after remove this input element everything is fine

but do we really need to format such date field?

Here is a date format binder used in the controller

```
@InitBinder
public void registerDateBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    DateFormat printFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("S-", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())); // format for data on the UI
    printFormat.setLenient(false);
    DateFormat sortFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"); // format for data get back from UI
    sortFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new ExpandableCustomDateEditor(printFormat, Arrays.asList(printFormat, sortFormat), true));
}
```

Comment: Set variable with session scope in EL.

Comment: confirm that EL is supported in the JSP version you are using.  specifically add ${2+2} to the page.  if it displays 4, then el is supported.  if it displays "${2+2}" then you are using an old version of JSP and el is not supported.  This may not be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

And just to add to the comments on the question, check the source of the first JSP to see if the hidden value is indeed being rendered as a date stored in orderDate or you're literally seeing ${orderDate}.  The view source should show you the results so you should be seeing a date if everything is indeed rendering and working properly.

Comment: Thanks but what is the difference between "well-rendered" date and literally ${orderDate}, what I can see from the source code is the date is look just like `Tue Sep 17 00:00:00 ART 2013` is it looks get rendered?

Comment: I think seeing the date basically answers the questions @ kayz1 and @DwB were mentioning.  At least we know that the date is indeed in the source code so that's one issue down.  "Well rendered" will depend on the library being used for parsing the content on the receiving end.  There's a lot of minor nuances to date formatting so it's sort of hard for me to advise anything since I just dont know enough of them off the top of my head.

Comment: It is a spring application so use a databinder, updated int he original post. the it seems the format of that date string `Tue Sep 17 00:00:00 ART 2013` should fit the `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` but very confused about why a http 400 pop up.

Comment: Hmm, now it's going beyond my scope (not a Spring person), but if the format looks right, I would double check with the "ART" abbreviation just to make sure it is something that is understood by the decoder.  Else you may have to use the slightly less convenient GMT format.  An easy check would be to simply replace ${orderDate} with "Tue Sep 17 00:00:00 GMT 2013" and see if it works.

Comment: ART is the locale, which is why make the situation so miserable, if it is and US locale then life could be much easier. Thanks.

Comment: well, the Java libraries are pretty well internationalized and it does seem like ART is a properly recognized timezone in the TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() list, so not quite sure if that's the problem.

It may simply come down to the parser on the other end expecting something different than what is output by the ${orderDate} format.  What that is, I have no idea.  Maybe it's a Spring default somewhere, or maybe there's an error message somewhere in one of the logs.